# How do you get and compare text stored in web page elements? Using Selenium, Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

What I want to do:

Take the message someone sends me via an online chat room (Omegle, ect, ect.)

Compare that message using if/elif statements.

Heres what i tried:

```
    #I tried getting the message from Omegle, hence 'strangermsg'

    msg = driver.find_element_by_class_name('strangermsg')
    if msg == "Hi":
        textbox.send_keys('option 1')
    elif():
        textbox.send_keys('option 2')
```

I believe the issue is that i'm not getting the element correctly, I am not sure how to get the directory for element_by_xpath.

Comment: Try `if msg.text == "Hi":`

Comment: Just copy and paste the path from source code or/and use ".text" to get just the text

Comment: I'm new to this website. Can someone tell me why this got a -1. Did I do something wrong? I thought I was very to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the text attribute of the webElement returned by find_element

```
#I tried getting the message from Omegle, hence 'strangermsg'

msg = driver.find_element_by_class_name('strangermsg')
if msg.text == "Hi":
    textbox.send_keys('option 1')
elif():
    textbox.send_keys('option 2')
```